# How can an Angular service and search component consume an api that returns promises

Tags: angular, promise, angular2-observables

I'm having trouble trying to understand how I can use the Elasticsearch Javascript client with Angular 4+? I know that Angular 4+ uses Observables to handle http requests and responses. The Elasticsearch JS client uses promises to return results. How can an Angular 4 service and component consume the Elasticsearch JS client api that returns promises? I've done some googling and came across some articles and tutorials - but none of them COMPLETELY answer my question. So I guess my question is how can my Angular 4 service and search component that uses Observables consume and api that returns promises?

Comment: What makes you think you can't use promises in an Angular app? What's the concrete problem you're facing?

Comment: Observable and Promise can be converted in both directions

Comment: @JBNizet, thanks for quick reply! I"m much more familiar with promises - how do you use promises in an Angular app? Lots of what I've seen online use Observables. Any links you can point me to?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer - any links that you can give me so I can see some good examples?

Comment: I have no links but Observable has a `toPromise` and I guess `merge` also accepts a `Promise`. There might be other ways to convert. I'm not using TypeScript myself.

Comment: you can also create `Obsevable`s  out of `Promise`s, if you want to go full Observable

Comment: You use them the same way as you use them in any other context. Again, I don't understand the problem.

Comment: Thanks everyone for all your comments, it just shows me that I need more understanding when it comes to using Observables/promises together - on to more reading/coding.